# Netty versus blocking socket performance

Tags: java, netty, nio

I have a simple standalone client-server test in which a client sends 500 bytes to a server and the server returns 2000 bytes back in response. It runs in a loop and I print time for every 50000 of such request/response calls. I compare performance of three implementations based on a blocking socket API, Netty and NIO2. The test shows that blocking socket performs significantly faster than Netty or NIO2. I understand that there is no concurrency in this test, which NIO was designed for. Still, does this difference in performance have an explanation or do I do something very inefficiently? Is there any way to improve Netty-based code to achieve performance close to blocking socket? I tried using a direct buffer for reading – no significant difference.

Tests were run with java 1.7.0_55 on two Linux servers in a gigabit network. Results of first four readings from these tests, in milliseconds, were:

- Blocking: 9754, 9307, 9305
- Netty: 14879, 11872, 11781
- NIO2: 14474, 12117, 12149

Another mystery is that Netty and NIO2 implementations run slow at the beginning and then stabilize. In a Netty case, stabilization happens after about 10000 cycles.

Below is the source code.

Config.java - used by all three implementations

```
public class Config {
    static final String HOST = "192.168.1.121";
    static final int PORT = 10000;

    static int requestLength = 500;
    static int responseLength = 2000;
    static int numOfCalls = 50000;

    static byte[] request = new byte[requestLength];
    static byte[] response = new byte[responseLength];
}
```

BlockingClient.java

```
public class BlockingClient {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Socket socket = null;
        try {
            socket = new Socket(Config.HOST, Config.PORT);

            InputStream is = socket.getInputStream();
            OutputStream os = socket.getOutputStream();
            int callCount = 0;

            long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

            while (true) {
                os.write(Config.request);
                read(is, Config.response);
                callCount++;
                if (callCount == Config.numOfCalls) {
                    System.out.println("numOfcalls=" + Config.numOfCalls + " time: " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime));
                    callCount = 0;
                    startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                socket.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public static void read(InputStream is, byte[] bytes) throws IOException {
        int num = 0;
        while(num < bytes.length) {
            num += is.read(bytes, num, bytes.length - num);
        }
    }

}
```

BlockingServer.java

```
public class BlockingServer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            ServerSocket srvSocket = new ServerSocket(Config.PORT);

            while (true) {
                final Socket socket = srvSocket.accept();

                new Thread() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        try {
                            InputStream is = socket.getInputStream();
                            OutputStream os = socket.getOutputStream();
                            while (true) {
                                BlockingClient.read(is, Config.request);
                                os.write(Config.response);
                            }
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } finally {
                            try {
                                socket.close();
                            } catch (IOException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }.start();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

NettyClient.java

```
    public final class NettyClient {

        public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
            EventLoopGroup group = new NioEventLoopGroup();
            try {
                Bootstrap b = new Bootstrap();
                b.group(group)
                 .channel(NioSocketChannel.class)
                 .handler(new ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel>() {
                    @Override
                    public void initChannel(SocketChannel ch) throws Exception {
                        ChannelPipeline p = ch.pipeline();
                        p.addLast(
                                new NettyClientHandler());
                    }
                 });

                b.connect(Config.HOST, Config.PORT).sync().channel().closeFuture().sync();

            } finally {
                group.shutdownGracefully();
            }
        }
    }
```

NettyClientHandler.java

```
public class NettyClientHandler extends ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter {

    private static ByteBuf responseBuf = Unpooled.wrappedBuffer(Config.response).clear();
    //private static ByteBuf responseBuf = Unpooled.directBuffer(Config.responseLength).clear();

    private int readLen = 0;
    private int callCount = 0;
    private long startTime;
    private long chunks = 0;

    @Override
    public void channelActive(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) {
        // Send the first message
        initLog();
        writeRequest(ctx);
    }

    @Override
    public void channelRead(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg) throws Exception {
        ByteBuf buf = (ByteBuf)msg;

        int received = buf.readableBytes();
        responseBuf.writeBytes(buf);
        readLen += received;
        chunks++;

        if (readLen == Config.responseLength) {
            if (responseBuf.isWritable()) {
                System.out.println("Error. responseBuf.isWritable()==true");
            }
            readLen = 0;
            responseBuf.clear();

            if (callCount++ == Config.numOfCalls - 1) {
                doLog();
                initLog();
            }
            writeRequest(ctx);

        } else if (readLen > Config.responseLength) {
            System.out.println("Error. readLen is too big: " + readLen);
        }

        buf.release();

    }

    private void initLog() {
        callCount = 0;
        chunks = 0;
        startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    }

    private void doLog() {
        System.out.println(Config.numOfCalls + " performed in " + chunks + " chunks, time: "+ (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime));
    }

    private void writeRequest(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) {
        ctx.writeAndFlush(Unpooled.wrappedBuffer(Config.request));
    }

    @Override
    public void channelInactive(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) throws Exception {
        ctx.fireChannelInactive();
    }

    @Override
    public void exceptionCaught(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Throwable cause) throws Exception {
        cause.printStackTrace();
        ctx.close();
    }

}
```

NettyServer.java

```
public final class NettyServer {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        EventLoopGroup group = new NioEventLoopGroup(1);
        try {
            ServerBootstrap b = new ServerBootstrap();
            b.group(group, group)
             .channel(NioServerSocketChannel.class)
             .childHandler(new ChannelInitializer<SocketChannel>() {
                @Override
                public void initChannel(SocketChannel ch) throws Exception {
                    ChannelPipeline p = ch.pipeline();
                    p.addLast(
                            new NettyServerHandler()
                    );
                }
             });

            b.bind(Config.PORT).sync().channel().closeFuture().sync();
        } finally {
            group.shutdownGracefully();
        }
    }
}
```

NettyServerHandler.java

```
public class NettyServerHandler extends ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter {

    private static ByteBuf requestBuf = Unpooled.wrappedBuffer(Config.request).clear();
    //private static ByteBuf requestBuf = Unpooled.directBuffer(Config.requestLength).clear();;

    private int readLen = 0;

    @Override
    public void channelRead(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg) throws Exception {
        ByteBuf buf = (ByteBuf)msg;

        int received = buf.readableBytes();
        requestBuf.writeBytes(buf);
        readLen += received;

        if (readLen == Config.requestLength) {
            if (requestBuf.isWritable()) {
                System.out.println("requestBuf.isWritable");
            }
            readLen = 0;
            requestBuf.clear();
            writeResponse(ctx);
        } else if (readLen > Config.responseLength) {
            System.out.println("readLen is too big: " + readLen);
        }

        buf.release();

    }

    private void writeResponse(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) {
        ctx.writeAndFlush(Unpooled.wrappedBuffer(Config.response));
    }

    @Override
    public void channelInactive(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) throws Exception {
        ctx.fireChannelInactive();
    }

    @Override
    public void exceptionCaught(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Throwable cause) throws Exception {
        cause.printStackTrace();
        ctx.close();
    }

}
```

Nio2Base.java

```
public abstract class Nio2Base {

    public static int numOfCalls = 50000;

    abstract ByteBuffer getWriteBuffer();
    abstract ByteBuffer getReadBuffer();
    abstract void messageReceived(ByteBuffer buffer);

    protected class ReadHandler implements CompletionHandler<Integer, Void> {
        private AsynchronousSocketChannel channel;
        private ByteBuffer buffer;

        ReadHandler(AsynchronousSocketChannel channel, ByteBuffer buffer) {
            this.channel = channel;
            this.buffer = buffer;
        }

        @Override
        public void completed(Integer result, Void a) {
            if (buffer.hasRemaining()) {
                channel.read(buffer, null, this);
            } else {
                messageReceived(buffer);
                buffer.clear();
                ByteBuffer writeBuffer = getWriteBuffer();
                channel.write(writeBuffer, null, new WriteHandler(channel, writeBuffer));
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void failed(Throwable exc, Void a) {
            exc.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    protected class WriteHandler implements CompletionHandler<Integer, Void> {
        private AsynchronousSocketChannel channel;
        private ByteBuffer buffer;

        WriteHandler(AsynchronousSocketChannel channel, ByteBuffer buffer) {
            this.channel = channel;
            this.buffer = buffer;
        }

        @Override
        public void completed(Integer result, Void attachment) {
            if (buffer.hasRemaining()) {
                channel.write(buffer, null, this);
            } else {
                buffer.clear();
                ByteBuffer readBuffer = getReadBuffer();
                channel.read(readBuffer, null, new ReadHandler(channel, readBuffer));
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void failed(Throwable exc, Void attachment) {
            exc.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Nio2Client.java

```
public class Nio2Client extends Nio2Base {

    private static ByteBuffer requestBuffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(Config.request);
    private static ByteBuffer readBuffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(Config.response);

    private int count;
    private long startTime;
    private AsynchronousSocketChannel channel;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        new Nio2Client().init();

        // Wait
        System.in.read();
    }

    public void init() {
        // create an asynchronous socket channel bound to the default group
        try {
            channel = AsynchronousSocketChannel.open();
            if (channel.isOpen()) {
                // connect this channel's socket
                channel.connect(new InetSocketAddress(Config.HOST, Config.PORT), null, new ConnectHandler(channel));
            } else {
                System.out.println("The asynchronous socket channel cannot be opened!");
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.err.println(ex);
        }
    }

    private class ConnectHandler implements CompletionHandler<Void, Void> {
        private AsynchronousSocketChannel channel;

        public ConnectHandler(AsynchronousSocketChannel channel) {
            this.channel = channel;
        }

        @Override
        public void completed(Void result, Void attachment) {
            try {
                System.out.println("Successfully connected at: " + channel.getRemoteAddress());
                ByteBuffer buffer = getWriteBuffer();
                startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                count = 0;
                channel.write(buffer, null, new WriteHandler(channel, buffer));

            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.err.println(e);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void failed(Throwable exc, Void attachment) {
            exc.printStackTrace();
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Connection cannot be established!");
        }

    }

    @Override
    ByteBuffer getWriteBuffer() {
        ByteBuffer ret = requestBuffer.duplicate();
        ret.position(ret.capacity());
        ret.flip();
        return ret;
    }

    @Override
    ByteBuffer getReadBuffer() {
        return (ByteBuffer)readBuffer.clear();
    }

    @Override
    void messageReceived(ByteBuffer buffer) {

        count++;

        if (count == numOfCalls) {

            System.out.println("Calls: " + count + " time: " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime));

            count = 0;
            startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        }
    }

}
```

Nio2Server.java

```
public class Nio2Server extends Nio2Base {

    private static byte[] response = new byte[Config.responseLength];
    private static ByteBuffer responseBuffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(response);
    private static ByteBuffer readBuffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(Config.request);


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Nio2Server().init();
    }

    public void init() {
        // create an asynchronous server socket channel bound to the default group
        try (AsynchronousServerSocketChannel serverChannel = AsynchronousServerSocketChannel.open()) {
            if (serverChannel.isOpen()) {

                // bind the server socket channel to local address
                serverChannel.bind(new InetSocketAddress(Config.HOST, Config.PORT));

                // display a waiting message while ... waiting clients
                System.out.println("Waiting for connections ...");

                AcceptHandler acceptHandler = new AcceptHandler(serverChannel);

                serverChannel.accept(null, acceptHandler);

                // Wait
                System.in.read();

            } else {
                System.out.println("The asynchronous server-socket channel cannot be opened!");
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            System.err.println(ex);
        }
    }

    private class AcceptHandler implements CompletionHandler<AsynchronousSocketChannel, Void> {
        private AsynchronousServerSocketChannel serverChannel;

        public AcceptHandler(AsynchronousServerSocketChannel serverChannel) {
            this.serverChannel = serverChannel;
        }

        @Override
        public void completed(AsynchronousSocketChannel channel, Void attachment) {

            serverChannel.accept(null, this);

            ByteBuffer buffer = getReadBuffer();

            try {
                System.out.println("Incoming connection from: " + channel.getRemoteAddress());

                channel.read(buffer, null, new ReadHandler(channel, buffer));

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void failed(Throwable exc, Void attachment) {
            exc.printStackTrace();
            serverChannel.accept(null, this);
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Cannot accept connections!");
        }
    }

    @Override
    ByteBuffer getWriteBuffer() {
        return responseBuffer.duplicate();
    }

    @Override
    ByteBuffer getReadBuffer() {
        return (ByteBuffer)readBuffer.clear();
    }

    @Override
    void messageReceived(ByteBuffer buffer) {
    }


}
```

Comment: Your `BlockingServer` isn't valid. It doesn't detect end of stream correctly.

Answer (score 1):

I'd assume the slow warm up is because of the JIT needing time to warm up, and NIO being much more complex than simple blocking IO (and needing more optimization).
I think blocking IO will be higher performance when there are only a few clients, as netty and NIO incur overhead for their complexity. However, NIO is far more *scalable* than blocking IO (especially with netty's epoll backend), and can handle thousands of clients easily.

Additionally, and most importantly, premature optimization is the root of all evil.
If you're writing a simple command line application, netty and NIO are overkill, and you should stick with blocking IO.
However, if you intend to write a robust, maintainable, and high-quality network application, you should use netty for the .
If you do later decide to switch from NIO to blocking IO, you cand do so seamlessly with netty, since netty also has a [blocking io backend](http://netty.io/4.1/api/index.html?io/netty/channel/oio/package-summary.html) which they 'recommend for a small number of connections'.